# Update a determinate field in a table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to modify a field of a determinate id, in my case the field is notify_datetime.
But when I run the app and try to do that, the app crashes giving this error.

**Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.msnma.movienotifier, PID: 4047
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: notify_datetime (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE MovieTypeTable SET notify_datetime=? WHERE notify_datetime = ?, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:910)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:521)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1856)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1799)
            at com.example.msnma.movienotifier.database.MovieDatabase.updateNotifyDate(MovieDatabase.java:299)
            at com.example.msnma.movienotifier.adapter.MoviesAdapter$9.onClick(MoviesAdapter.java:445)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

The method is called *updateNotifyDate* and should modify *notify_datetime*.

**MovieDatabase.java**

```
package com.example.msnma.movienotifier.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.MainActivity;
import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.databaseModel.MovieDBModel;
import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.databaseModel.TypeDBModel;
import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.mapper.MovieMapper;
import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.model.Movie;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MovieDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movieDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_MOVIE = "MovieTable";
    private static final String TABLE_TYPE = "TypeTable";
    private static final String TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE = "MovieTypeTable";
    //Table Fields
    private static final String MOVIE_ID ="movie_id";
    public static final String TITLE ="title";
    private static final String OVERVIEW = "overview";
    private static final String POSTER_URL = "posterUrl";
    private static final String BACKDROP_URL = "backdropUrl";
    private static final String TRAILER_URL = "trailerUrl";
    private static final String RELEASE_DATE = "releaseDate";
    private static final String RATING = "rating";
    private static final String ADULT = "adult";

    private static final String TYPE_ID = "type_id";
    private static final String TYPE_DESCR = "type_descr";

    private static final String MOVIE_TYPE_ID = "movie_type_id";
    private static final String M_ID = "movie_id";
    private static final String T_ID = "type_id";
    private static final String notify_datetime = "notify_datetime";

    // Table Create Statements
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_MOVIE + "(" + MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + OVERVIEW + " TEXT," + POSTER_URL + " TEXT," + BACKDROP_URL + " TEXT," + TRAILER_URL + " TEXT,"
            + RATING + " REAL," + ADULT + " INTEGER," + RELEASE_DATE + " DATETIME," + notify_datetime + " DATETIME"  + ")";

    // Tag table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TYPE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TYPE
            + "(" + TYPE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + TYPE_DESCR + " TEXT" + ")";

    // todo_tag table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE + "(" + MOVIE_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + M_ID + " INTEGER," + T_ID + " INTEGER" + ")";

    static SQLiteDatabase database;

    public MovieDatabase(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        database = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TYPE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE);
        insertType(db); //NOTA: questo va chiamato solo la prima volta che instanziamo il DB, AGGIUNGERE CONTROLLO!
        //in teoria onCreate verrà chiamato solo la prima volta...
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MOVIE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TYPE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }
    //questa funzione serve solo per inserire casualmente dai suggested movies, alcuni notify e watched movies
    public static void saveMoviesOnDB(List<Movie> movies, String type){
        MovieDatabase db = MainActivity.getMovieDatabase();
        MovieMapper mapper = new MovieMapper();
        List<MovieDBModel> moviesDB = mapper.toMovieDBModelList(movies);
        Integer typeId = 0;
        int index = 0;
        if(type.equals("notify")){
            typeId = 1;
        }else if(type.equals("watched")){
            typeId = 2;
            index = index+5;
        }else{
            //todo catch invalid type Id exception
        }
        for(int a = index; a<index+5; a++){
            insertMovie(moviesDB.get(a), typeId, db);
        }
    }
    //open the database, maybe not useful...
    public MovieDatabase open() throws SQLException
    {
        database = getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // closing database
    public void closeDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }

    //CRUDs
    public static void insertMovie(MovieDBModel movie, Integer typeId, MovieDatabase db) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getWritableDatabase();
        if(checkMovieUniqueness(movie.getTitle(), db)) {        //NON VOGLIO INSERIRE PIù VOLTE LO STESSO FILM
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(TITLE, movie.getTitle());
            values.put(OVERVIEW, movie.getOverview());
            values.put(POSTER_URL, movie.getPosterUrl());
            values.put(BACKDROP_URL, movie.getBackdropUrl());
            values.put(TRAILER_URL, movie.getTrailerUrl());
            values.put(RELEASE_DATE, movie.getReleaseDate().toString());
            values.put(RATING, movie.getRating());
            values.put(ADULT, movie.isAdult());
            //inizio nuovo codice
            if(typeId == 1) {
                values.put(notify_datetime, movie.getNotifyDate().toString());
                Log.i("TYPEID", "Siamo dentro");
            }
            //else values.putNull(NOTIFY_TIME_DATE);
            //fine nuovo codice
            // insert row
            long movieId = database.insert(TABLE_MOVIE, null, values);
            insertMovieType(movieId, typeId, db);
        }
    }

    public static void insertMovieType(Long movieId, Integer typeId, MovieDatabase db){
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(M_ID, movieId.intValue());
        values.put(T_ID, typeId);

        database.insert(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, null, values);
    }

    private void insertType(SQLiteDatabase db){

        ContentValues descr1 = new ContentValues();
        descr1.put(TYPE_DESCR, "NOTIFY");

        ContentValues descr2 = new ContentValues();
        descr2.put(TYPE_DESCR, "WATCHED");

        // insert row
        db.insert(TABLE_TYPE, null, descr1);
        db.insert(TABLE_TYPE, null, descr2);
    }

    private TypeDBModel getTypeByTypeDescr(String typeDescr) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TYPE + " WHERE "
                + TYPE_DESCR + " = " + typeDescr;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        TypeDBModel td = new TypeDBModel();
        td.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TYPE_ID)));
        td.setDescription((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TYPE_DESCR))));

        return td;
    }

    private static boolean checkMovieUniqueness(String movieTitle, MovieDatabase db) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIE + " WHERE "
                + TITLE + " = " + "'"+ movieTitle + "'";

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            c.close();
            return false;
        }else{
            c.close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public List<MovieDBModel> getAllMovieByType(String typeDescr) throws ParseException {
        List<MovieDBModel> movies = new ArrayList<MovieDBModel>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIE + " mv, "
                + TABLE_TYPE + " type, " + TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE + " tmt WHERE type."
                + TYPE_DESCR + " = '" + typeDescr + "'" + " AND type." + TYPE_ID
                + " = " + "tmt." + T_ID + " AND mv." + MOVIE_ID + " = "
                + "tmt." + M_ID;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MovieDBModel td = new MovieDBModel();
                td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_ID))));
                td.setTitle((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TITLE))));
                td.setOverview(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(OVERVIEW)));
                td.setPosterUrl(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(POSTER_URL))));
                td.setBackdropUrl((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(BACKDROP_URL))));
                td.setTrailerUrl(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TRAILER_URL)));
                String dateString =c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(RELEASE_DATE)));
                Date date = sdf3.parse(dateString);
                td.setReleaseDate(date);
                td.setRating((c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(RATING))));
                int adult = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ADULT));
                if(adult == 0){
                    td.setAdult(true);          //NOT sure if is the contrary
                }else{
                    td.setAdult(false);
                }
                //nuovo codice
                String datenotifyString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(notify_datetime));
                if(datenotifyString != null)
                {
                    Date datenotify = sdf3.parse(datenotifyString);
                    td.setNotifyDate(datenotify);
                }
                        //fine nuovo codice
                movies.add(td);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return movies;
    }

    public void deleteMovie(long tado_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_MOVIE, MOVIE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(tado_id) });
    }

    public void deleteMovieType(long tado_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, M_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(tado_id) });
    }

    public int updateMovieType(long id, long tag_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(T_ID, tag_id);

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, values, M_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }

    //da sistemare.

    public int updateNotifyDate(long id, Date datetime ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(notify_datetime,datetime.toString());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, values, notify_datetime + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() throws ParseException {
        boolean isEmpty = false;
        List<MovieDBModel> movie1 = getAllMovieByType("NOTIFY");
        List<MovieDBModel> movie2 = getAllMovieByType("WATCHED");
        if(movie1.isEmpty() && movie2.isEmpty()){
            isEmpty = true;
        }
        return isEmpty;
    }

    public static List<MovieDBModel> getAllMovies() throws ParseException {
        List<MovieDBModel> movies = new ArrayList<MovieDBModel>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIE;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = database;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MovieDBModel td = new MovieDBModel();
                td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_ID))));
                td.setTitle((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TITLE))));
                td.setOverview(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(OVERVIEW)));
                td.setPosterUrl(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(POSTER_URL))));
                td.setBackdropUrl((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(BACKDROP_URL))));
                td.setTrailerUrl(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TRAILER_URL)));
                String dateString =c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(RELEASE_DATE)));
                Date date = sdf3.parse(dateString);
                td.setReleaseDate(date);
                td.setRating((c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(RATING))));
                int adult = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ADULT));
                if(adult == 0){
                    td.setAdult(true);          //NOT sure if is the contrary
                }else{
                    td.setAdult(false);
                }

                movies.add(td);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return movies;
    }
}
```

**In MoviesAdapter.java only piece that call updateNotifyDate:**

```
MovieDatabase md = new MovieDatabase(context);
                            Log.i("IDMOVIE","ID:"+movies.get(position).getId());
                            md.updateNotifyDate(movies.get(position).getId(),datatime);
                        }
```

[image: Sqlite movie_table datebase]

Why it doesn't work? What am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to update `MovieTypeTable` but your image suggests the `notify_datetime` is in `MovieTable` so it's throwing `SQLiteException: no such column`.

Comment: ok thank you, you're right. Now it doesn't crash but the notify_datetime is not update. Some idea?